# Simple app for tvOS - but not simple for me. Looping my movie

Tags: xcode, swiftui, tvos

I'm total newbie in coding and are trying to make a small app for my own.
This is working as I want but I've no idea how to make the movie loop? Tried to look everywhere but to difficult for me.

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  VideoWallPaperV5
//
//  Created by Me on 13/04/2022.
//


import SwiftUI
import AVKit


struct ContentView: View {
    
    let player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "small_movie", withExtension: "mp4")!)

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
                    .onAppear {
                        player.play()
//                        player.isMuted = true
                    }

            
            VStack{
                Text("Airplay to kitchen")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.black.cornerRadius(10).opacity(0.6))
                    .position(x: 200, y: 100)
                    .font(Font.custom("Hill", size: 33))
                    .lineSpacing(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    Spacer()
}

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AVPlayerLooper provides a simple interface to loop a single AVPlayerItem. You create a player looper by passing it a reference to your AVQueuePlayer which you create by passing a reference to your AVPlayer.

Check out Apples documentation:

[AvPlayerLooper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper)

[AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer)

Comment: Thanks but its way out of my knowledge :) I cannot merge that into my player

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop your videoItem you should probably use AVQueuePlayer and AVPlayerLooper as it is the most proper way for your task.

But if you insist on using only AVPlayer and its interface you need to subscribe to `NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime`

And handle this notification by seeking to position 0.0 and triggering playback with `play()`

kinda pseudocode would look like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(itemPlayToEndTime),
                                       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)


private func itemPlayToEndTime() {
    let time = CMTime(seconds: 0.0, preferredTimescale: 1)
    self.player.seek(to: time) { [weak self] completed in 
        guard completed else { return }
        self?.player.play() 
}
```

but I strongly recommend you learn about using AVQueuePlayer.